# Windsor-Castle: Register All Types in assembly using config file

Tags: c#, configuration, castle-windsor, registration

in code i can do some thing like this:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("AssemblyName"));
```

can i do the same thing using Configuration file "Windsor.Config"???

Comment: Why? Why do you not want to do it in code?

Comment: well, i am working on a huge project which involves more than 30 modules.

each module is responsible for providing a presentation UI for a corresponding subsystem.
each subsystem has a: domain, repository, core, application service ..etc
and all of these assemblies has to be registered in the main container.
so either i have to register them in the module' code (which means that i should reference them all to the module)

or i have to modify the main windsor configuration file (which is annoying) every time i need to register a new component.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Responding to your comment.

There's also a 3rd way (in Windsor 2.5, currently in beta 2 - final release is expected very soon).

You can have each of your modules reference Windsor, and each module have its own set of [Installers.](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx)

Than you can use the new directory scanning capability to install components from all these assemblies:

```
// In your root assembly
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Install(   
   FromAssembly.This(),
   FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("Modules")),
   Configuration.FromAppConfig()
)
```

In addition if you have components following identical structure you can also register components from multiple assemblies in single installer. [See more here.](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#codeDefaultInterfacecode_7)

```
container.Register(
   AllTypes.FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("Modules"))
      .Where(t=>t.Namespace.EndsWith(".Services"))
      .WithService.DefaultInterface()
);
```

Comment: Very cool! I didn't know about this overload for Install(). I usually resolve all the installers first and then call Install() individually.

Comment: Krzysztof : you are my hero :)

unfortunately i can't vote at the time being.
i would vote for 15.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that only with the fluent configuration API can you set up conventions for your application so that as you create new components you aren’t required to register them individually, as you example shows.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a trivial facility to do that, e.g.:

**AllTypesConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <facilities>
    <facility id="alltypes">
      <assemblies>
        <item>Castle.Core</item>
      </assemblies>
    </facility>
  </facilities>
</configuration>
```

**code:**

```
public class AllTypesFacility : AbstractFacility {
    protected override void Init() {
        var asmList = FacilityConfig.Children["assemblies"].Children;
        foreach (var asm in asmList)
            Kernel.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed(asm.Value).Pick());
    }
}


var container = new WindsorContainer(@"..\..\AllTypesConfig.xml");
container.AddFacility("alltypes", new AllTypesFacility());
container.Resolve<NullLogger>();
```

If you need more flexibility it will get progressively harder to represent the fluent config in XML.